# How do I correctly implement a basic first person camera in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I am new to OpenGL and was trying to create a simple maze that i can traverse through using a first person perspective. I have the maze rendering and all that just fine. But my first person camera perspective ends up being more of a third person camera. The camera revolves around a certain point infront of the camera.

My Code for actual rotation and translation

```
void camera(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(pitch, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(yaw, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(player.x, player.y, player.z);
}
```

This is also the first translations and rotations that happen in rendering.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: "The camera revolves around a certain point infront of the camera." What is it about what you're seeing that makes you say that? The only way that could be possible is if the `player` location changes when you rotate the view.

Comment: I drew a little pyramid at `player` and the camera when rotating revolves around that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera transformation needs to be inverted, so that you are moving the camera position, in this case the position of the player, to the origin:

```
glTranslatef(-player.x, -player.y, -player.z);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you build your maze, leave it alone, and then use gluLookAt() to have your first-person perspective.  What you're doing now is standing still and moving the maze around you. You're doing it the hard way.

Comment: There is literally no difference between what you just said and what he is doing, save that he's using a couple of rotations and a translation while you suggest `gluLookAt`. All `gluLookAt` does is generate a matrix, just like he's doing. Moving the world around a fixed camera is no different from moving a fixed camera through the world. It all ends up in the same place: relative to a fixed camera-space, ready for projection. It's a conceptual difference, not a code difference.